# Kodein Framework - property delegate must have a provideDelegate(...) method

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, delegates, kodein

I'm trying to build an app with the following architecture: LoginActivity -> MainActivity -> everything else handled in fragments hosted by MainActivity. I'm also using the Kodein Framework for the first time and get the following error in my starting fragment:

> Property delegate must have a 'provideDelegate(HomeFragment,
>   KProperty*>' method. None of the following functions is suitable. 
>   provideDelegate(Context [highlighted in red], KProperty<*>?) defined
>   in org.kodein.di.android.KodeinPropertyDelegateProvider Type
>   'KodeinPropertyDelegateProvider' has no method
>   'getValue(HomeFragment, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a
>   delegate

This is my code so far:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(), KodeinAware {

override val kodein by kodein()
private val factory : MainViewModelFactory by instance()
private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val binding : FragmentHomeBinding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, factory).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    binding.viewModel = viewModel

    return binding.root
}
```

}

How can I fix this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, adding a type declaration after kodein did the trick... :)

Comment: Hi, I just changed `override val kodein by kodein()` to `override val kodein: Kodein by kodein()` and it worked. Hope it helps!

Comment: Not working in case of fragments. Need to use 'import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein' in case of fragment but for activity 'import org.kodein.di.android.kodein' works fine. Can you  elaborate the difference between both imports?

Answer (score 1):

In your imports change

```
import org.kodein.di.android.kodein
```

to

```
import org.kodein.di.android.x.kodein
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
override val kodein:Kodein by kodein()
```